# how use array in x-ref alpinejs?

Tags: alpine.js

i have a code like this:

```
<section x-data="assistant" class="section-space section-space-top-40">
    <div class="container">
        <span x-ref="link">test</span>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    function assistant() {
        return {
            link: null,
            init() {
                this.$refs.link.textContent = "change"
            },
        }    
    }
</script>
```

and works fine , but if i wanna use array as ref

```
<section x-data="assistant" class="section-space section-space-top-40">
    <div class="container">
        <span x-ref="link[0]">test</span>
        <span x-ref="link[1]">test</span>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    function assistant() {
        return {
            link: null,
            init() {
                console.log(this.$refs.link)
            },
        }    
    }
</script>
```

log shows me `undefined` how can i fix it? it is alpineJS and have no idea what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok done it. Maybe is not as i would like, so if you know better way, please share with us.

```
<ul x-data="quiz" class="user-nav">
    <template x-for="(question, index) in questions">
       <li>
           <span :x-ref="'topic-' + question.id" x-text="question.text"></span>
       </li>
    </template>
</ul>

<script>
    function quiz() {
        return {
           init() {
            let ref = document.querySelector('[x-ref="topic-' + id + '"]');
           ref.textContent = "change"
</script>
```

first change was add : to x-fer like :x-ref
and after get id to script i can change selected text